# What's wrong in solving this limit $\lim_{ x\to 0}=\frac{f(2x)+4x^2-2x}{x^2}$, if $f(x)=e^x - x^2 -1$

Tags: limits

If $$f(x)=e^x - x^2 -1$$

Then $$\lim_{ x\to 0}=\frac{f(2x)+4x^2-2x}{x^2}$$
$$\lim_{ x\to 0}=\frac{e^{2x} -1-2x}{x^2}$$
$$\lim_{ x\to 0}=2\frac{e^{2x} -1}{2x\cdot x}-\frac{2}{x}$$

What i did wrong , why I am getting limit as 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up to $$\frac{e^{2x} -1-2x}{x^2}$$ Everything is correct but when $x\to 0$, both numerator and denominator tend to $0$.

Do not split the expression.

So, use either L'Hôpital rule or Taylor series and prove that the limit does exist.

Comment: Why splitting leading us to wrong answer?

Comment: Because the term $-2/x$ does not have a limit as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Because doing it you have $x^2$ in the first denominator and $x$ in the second which makes you more lost than if looking at the whole expression. In fact, this is the mistake to almost never repeat. Cheers.